# Contact Synchronisation with Android

Tags: android, sync, thunderbird, mint, contacts

I am using thunderbird as my mail client at my workplace PC (Linux Mint) and personal laptop (Ubuntu). I am using the thunderbird address-book synchroniser add on for synchronisation of contacts.

Now, I am planning to buy an android phone. So is there any android app which will help me synchronise the contacts and calenders across all my devices via cloud? The best would be if thunderbird had an android version, but I don't mind moving to a new synchronisation add on or mail client so long as I don't have to abandon the Ubuntu and Mint.

Comment: You can [caldav](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib&hl=en) [carddav](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.Sync&hl=en) sync with any caldav/carddav server without using Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using android device, you should have a google account so that you may use Google Apps like Google Play Store. I suggest to you that you should make a gmail account, export all your contacts from your previous email (personal) in .csv format and then import these contacts in gmail by uploading .csv file. When you will setup your android device with the google account (gmail), it will automatically sync all contacts from google into your phone

Comment: My personal email id is not with gmail. In fact, even if I can get any other good mail client which works on Linux and android, and can synch across devices, that will help.

Comment: For using android device, you should have a google account so that you may use Google Apps like Google Play Store. I suggest to you that you should make a gmail account, export all your contacts from your previous email (personal) in .csv format and then import these contacts in gmail by uploading .csv file.
When you will setup your android device with the google account (gmail), it will automatically sync all contacts from google into your phone.

Comment: I have a google account, just not a gmail associated with it. Anyway, so what you said can be done without abandoning my email account? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I have great privacy concerns about uploading my contacts to google since it tends to find a lot of information about them which I don't want to see (and guess it reciprocates the favour) and makes the list or parts of the list public. I am not much into sharing and social networking, just want a simple synchronised, PRIVATE contact list. And definitely not ready to go through a hell lot of complicated settings and privacy statements of google contacts. Maybe my fear stems from my ignorance of the settings. Anyway, you tried your best and accepting it.